# Close current view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a page called `PayOut.cshtml`. On this page, I have a button called `Pay`, which opens a new small window called `Authenticate.cshtml` for a user to authenticate himself by specifying his email and password.

Once a user has been authenticated, the the `Authenticate.cshtml` should be dismissed, and showing a button called `Confirm` in the `PayOut.cshtml` page.

I have tried the following:

```
public AuthenticateController(Authenticate obj)
{
      var success = false;

      if (auth) {
         success = true;
      }

      return View("close");
}
```

View for close:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.close();
    </script>
</body>
```

How can I dismiss the the authenticate view and show a button in the PayOut view by using session ? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "postMessage", in the main window use something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <header>
      <title>PostMessage Demo</title>
  </header>
  <body>
    <button id="btn" onclick="openPopup();">Open Popup</button>
    <script>

        window.addEventListener("message", onMessage, false);

        function onMessage(event){
            document.getElementById("btn").innerText = "you typed " + event.data;
            document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
        };

        function openPopup(){
            document.getElementById("btn").textContent = "popup active";
            document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
            window.open("/popup", "popup window");
        }

     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Then in the popup window this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <title>Popup</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        <input id="textEdit" type="text" value=""></input>
        <button onclick="_close();">Close popup</button>
        <script>

            function _close(){
            let pUri = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
            window.opener.postMessage(document.getElementById("textEdit").value, pUri);
            window.close();
        }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you click the "Close popup" button in the popup window it will close and trigger the onMessage event in the main window with the text you typed in the "textEdit" input.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, the specs actually don't allow this. Although, I just tested this with Edge, Chrome, Firefox, and IE and it worked. Could you clarify how it didn't work?

Anyway, I decided to try another method that doesn't involve a window trying to close itself and it worked in the same four browsers.

In Payout.cshtml

```
   var newWindow;
    function authenticate() {
        newWindow = window.open("@Url.Action("Authenticate")");
        window.setTimeout(tryCloseWindow, 5000);
    }
    function tryCloseWindow() {
        try {
            if (newWindow.closeMe == undefined) {
                window.setTimeout(tryCloseWindow, 1000);
                return;
            }
        } catch(ex) {
            // window was closed by user
            return;
        }

        newWindow.close();
    }
```

Authenticate.cshtml

```
<button onclick="pay();">pay</button>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function pay() {
            window.location = "@Url.Action("Close")";
        }
    </script>
}
```

Close.cshtml

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        window.closeMe = true;
    </script>
}
```

Comment: How can I show the button Confirm when the popup window is dismissed ?

Comment: Well, after newWindow.close(), and assuming you have a button that's hidden, document.getElementById("confirmButton").style.display = "block";